# words are stemming while parsing using itext library in java

Tags: java, parsing, itext

```
        public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        text = renderInfo.getText().toLowerCase();
          System.out.println("@   "+text);
        Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.getBaseline().getStartPoint();
        Vector topRight = renderInfo.getAscentLine().getEndPoint();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(curBaseline.get(0), curBaseline.get(1),      topRight.get(0), topRight.get(1));
        float curFontSize = rect.getHeight();
        int size = (int) curFontSize;
        at[i][0] = "" + size;
        at[i++][1] = text;
        //System.out.println(text);
    }
```

i used this code to extract words from the pdf,but when i am getting words splitting like
security as 
s
e
curity
and words which contains v&e are dividing as 2 words
how to modify the code so that i can get exact word as it is using itext library?

Comment: Aha, you're getting each snippet of text separately. You should compare the end point of each snippet with the start point of each other snippet, and compare that distance with the width of the space character. That is what iText does internally when you use the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` instead of asking iText to feed you every snippet of text available in the content stream of a page.

Comment: The text associated with such a `TextRenderInfo` instance is not necessarily a word; it merely is a text chunk drawn in a single text drawing operation in the PDF; it may be merely part of a word, a whole word or even a whole text line; furthermore it can also be the end of one word and the start of the next, etc. Thus, the `RenderListener` implementation has to recognize words out of this text soup.    @BrunoLowagie Maybe you should simply make that pointer towards the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` an actual answer. What else could be answered?

Comment: how can i get width of the word?

Comment: i can't get what said,how can i "compare that distance with the width of the space character" ?

Comment: The core of abhishyam's problem is his (wrong) assumption that there is such a thing as a "word" in a PDF. There are only snippets of text that look like words to the human eye. I will stop looking at this question as it is very frustrating trying to explain something to somebody who "doesn't get" what I'm saying.

Comment: sir @Bruno Lowagie i understand that,but u told that "compare that distance with the width of the space character",how can i do it?

Comment: The answer is in your question, isn't it? You use methods such as `renderInfo.getBaseline().getEndPoint()` and `renderInfo.getBaseline().getStartPoint()`. In iText's `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` all `TextRenderInfo` instances are ordered based on their coordinates and all end points are compared with the start point of the next snippet. What more is there to say? mkl and I have given you all the info you need to start coding.